# Linux pass-through routing

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing

I have a reasonably ordinary Linux machine with two ethernet
interfaces which I'll call eth0 and eth1, and a WiFi interface
which I'll call wlan0.

For various reasons, I do *not* want this machine to talk directly
out over its WiFi interface.  Instead, I want it to treat eth0 as
its gateway to everything.

But then I'd like a router on this machine's LAN (that is,
reachable via eth0) to be able to use this machine's WiFi
interface as a bridge out to the rest of the world.  My
colleagues and I have the idea that the router can ship packets
back to this machine on eth1, and this machine can forward them
to wlan0.  Similarly, any incoming packets on wlan0 will be sent
immediately back out over eth1 for the local router to deal with.

We're pursuing this topology because we believe a dedicated
router can make better routing decisions, and more easily, than
if we tried to teach the Linux machine in question to be a proper
router.  (It's not straightforward, because the WiFi link is (a)
not always up and (b) not the only link out to the rest of our
world.  Also (c) other hosts on this LAN may want to send packets
over the WiFi link also, and (d) packets for those other hosts
may arrive over it.)

I know there are a number of ways to route packets between two
interfaces like this.  I could use a bridge interface, or I could
use iptables.  For the moment I've been pursuing iptables.  (The
machine is a bit too old to use nft.)

What I'm not sure of is:

1. whether eth1 and wlan0 need their own IP addresses and
2. if they do, how hard I'll have to work to keep this machine from using them directly.

As a bare minimum I had imagined I could do something like

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

as in [iptables forwarding between two interfaces](https://serverfault.com/questions/431593/iptables-forwarding-between-two-interface).
Notionally, this turns the Linux box into a wire between the two
interfaces, blindly and bidirectionally forwarding all packets
without inspecting or altering them in any way.

I'm afraid, though, that this may be naive, and not work, because
it won't ARP right, and stuff.

I suspect I probably do need to assign IP addresses to eth1 and
wlan0.  And if I do that, I suspect I'll probably need to (at
least) rewrite the source addresses of packets as I forward them.
Per an answer at [that question I linked to](https://serverfault.com/questions/431593), that might be as
easy as adding

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

and maybe also

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

to my iptables recipe.

Also, if I do assign IP addresses to those two interfaces, I want
to make sure the local Linux machine doesn't try to use them for
anything else.  I might need to create some explicit don't-route
rules in the routing table, to force it to send everything out
over eth0, even if it seems to match the subnets assigned to eth1
and/or wlan0.

Does anyone have any advice on how to make this work?  (Or advice that it's a bad idea and will never work, I suppose, although I'm hoping it will.)

This is an isolated local network, by the way, not connected to
the global Internet at all.  Everything has fixed private-use
addresses; there is no DHCP going on and no NATting required.

Comment: Could you please draw a diagram of how is everything connected? System has three NICs, eth0, eth1, wlan0; what's behind each NIC and why it needs to forward packets? For whom?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you basically want that NUC to function as a switch between your eth1 and wlan0? If so, you can create a network bridge with iproute2 (`ip link add type bridge ...`) or with bridge-utils (`brctl addbr ...`) and add the two interfaces. It's not required to assign an IP addresses on those interfaces. In that case, your eth0 will be the only interface with an IP address and will just work as if it was the only active network interface.

Comment: I don't know what "NUC" is, but yes, I want to bridge eth1 and wlan0 as if there were a wire between them (is that what you meant by "function as a switch between"?).  I don't seem to have the `brctl` command — is that something in the bridge-utils package?  I don't know what iproute2 is, or where I would try that `ip link add …` syntax.  (But thanks for these leads!)

Comment: Looks like `ebtables` might be Yet Another possibility.

Comment: NUC is a Next Unit of Compute, basically a small PC from Intel. Somewhere aloung the way I somehow thought you were running a NUC :p Anyway, replace NUC is "the PC".

Comment: As for ```brctl```, it is indeed part of the ```bridge-utils``` package, and ```iproute2``` contains the ```ip``` command. You can typically install them though apt, yum or whatever package manager you're using. You should find plenty of examples online on how to create a bridge between 2 interfaces using those utilities.

Comment: WiFi NIC could not be used as a bridge port on a WLAN client (mobile station). Also, brctl and bridge-utils are long time obsolete, the functionality was moved into ip and bridge tools from iproute2, and enhanced afterwards, it's now support VLAN-aware bridges and qinq, which you can't achieve with bridge-utils.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov *WiFi NIC could not be used as a bridge port on a WLAN client* Why not?

Comment: Because 802.11 (WiFi) packet format has no usable provision for that. It only has a place for three MAC addresses: STA, AP and anything behind AP. STA authenticates to AP with its MAC address and if it tries to send anything with another address such packet will be rejected by the AP as not authentic. So only AP is able to bridge wireless networks. There is another, 4-address packet format, but it's not standardised fully and therefore unusable.